# Getting error of Gradle sync failed

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting error of

> Gradle sync failed: Could not find
>   org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824. Searched in the following
>   locations:
>   file:/D:/android/gradle/m2repository/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
>   file:/D:/android/gradle/m2repository/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
>   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
>   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
>   https://maven.google.com/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
>   https://maven.google.com/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
>   Required by: project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1 >
>   com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.0.1 >
>   com.android.tools.lint:lint:26.0.1 >
>   com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:26.0.1 >
>   com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:26.0.1 >
>   com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.0.1 Consult
>   IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
  > distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME  distributionPath=wrapper/dists 
  > zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME  zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
  > distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

**build.gradle**

> ```
>    buildscript {
>     repositories {
>         jcenter()
>         google()
>     }
>
>     dependencies {
>         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
>     } }/* buildscript {
> repositories {
>     mavenCentral()
>     maven {
>         url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
>         url 'https://maven.google.com/'
>         name 'Google'
>     }
> }
> dependencies {
>     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
> } }*/ allprojects {
> apply plugin: "eclipse"
> apply plugin: "idea"
>
> version = '1.0'
> ext {
>     appName = 'Basketball'
>     gdxVersion = '1.6.3'
>     roboVMVersion = '1.4.0'
>     box2DLightsVersion = '1.3'
>     ashleyVersion = '1.4.0'
>     aiVersion = '1.5.0'
> }
>
> repositories {
>     mavenCentral()
>     maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
>     maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
>
> } } project(":desktop") {
> apply plugin: "java"
>
>
> dependencies {
>     compile project(":core")
>     compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
>     compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
>     compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
>     compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
> } } project(":android") {
> apply plugin: "android"
>
> configurations { natives }
>
> dependencies {
>     compile project(":core")
>     compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
>     natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
>     natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
>     natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
>     compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
>     natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
>     natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
>     natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
>     compile project(":BaseGameUtils")
>     compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
> } } project(":core") {
> apply plugin: "java"
>
>
> dependencies {
>     compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
>     compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
>     compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
> } } tasks.eclipse.doLast {
> delete ".project" } /*android {
> compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:24' } dependencies { }*/
> ```

Can anyone please help me in this i am not getting any resolution on google as well.

Comment: Is gradle able to download other dependencies? Maybe this is a network/proxy/... issue?

Comment: as per error i checked in path trove4j folder is not available in in jetbrains folder and checked in repo1.maven and maven.google there also this trove4j not available

Comment: You have more typos than words in that comment. And you did not answer my question.

Comment: no gradle is not able to download other dependencies.not using any proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error and it could not seem to find the maven artifact "org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824".

There is no such one in maven central, but there is one in the jcenter repository:
https://bintray.com/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j

Add jcenter() to the repositories {} of your allprojects {} block and it should work.